# wouldn't specifying -t with -i be redundant for docker run?

Tags: linux, docker, containers

This post fleshes most of this out: [Confused about Docker -t option to Allocate a pseudo-TTY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30137135/confused-about-docker-t-option-to-allocate-a-pseudo-tty)

But if  "-i" gives me a stdin stream and -t gives me a whole terminal driver isn't -i redundant if I use them together? Or is it that with just -t I can *only* access it via ssh but if I add -i I can also pipe it input directly from the console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I remember reading about it a while ago in the documentation. I had a look and I found:

> For interactive processes (like a shell), you must use -i -t together
>   in order to allocate a tty for the container process. -i -t is often
>   written -it as you’ll see in later examples. Specifying -t is
>   forbidden when the client is receiving its standard input from a pipe,
>   as in:

In the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#foreground). I use `--ti` a lot and always write it as `ti`, I guess thats why a google search yields little result. The documentation mentions `it` a lot but not once mentions `ti`

---

#### The technical side of things

The OP asked me to go into a bit more detail so here it is...

The `-i` flag means "interactive" (replaceable with --interactive as well). This **basically** means that the shell will remain open even if it has nothing to do. (e.g waiting for user input).

An example of an *interactive* shell would be a standard terminal window / command prompt. It will stay open and wait for your input (e.g interaction), upon receiving input it executes a task.

An example of a *non-interactive* shell would be a simple bash script. The script will run but won't offer any interaction with the shell. (although it's possible to emulate an interactive shell with the read statement.

Specifying -t without -i would therefor mean that the tty would immediatelly disband, seeing as it wouldn't actually "run" anything and since you didn't start it interactively it won't wait for your input.

More info about interactive vs non-interactive can be found [here](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/intandnonint.html).

Comment: that I guess that confirms what I thought, but its too bad there isn't a more lower level explanation I think that would improve my understanding of docker itself.

Comment: check back in a minute ;)

Comment: ok @red888, you can check back now :P I added the explanation :)