# what is docker run -it flag?

Tags: docker, dockerfile, command-line-arguments

I was doing some complex stuff with docker, but as turn out I don't know what `-it` flag means.
Recently I've come across on some example of `docker run` command which has confused me a little.

```
docker run -itd ubuntu:xenial /bin/bash
```

My question is what is sense to write `-it` flag here, if container during instantiation run `bin/bash`

In documentation we have an example

```
docker run --name test -it debian
```

with explanation

> The -it instructs Docker to allocate a pseudo-TTY connected to the
> container’s stdin; creating an interactive bash shell in the
> container.

and explanation for `-t` flag from help page

> -t, --tty                     Allocate a pseudo-TTY

if I delete `-it` flag during

```
docker run -d ubuntu:xenial /bin/bash
```

my newly created container doesn't live so much

in `docker ps -a`

it is designated as exited

Sorry, if my question quite stupid, I can't find explanation on the Internet (I have significant misunderstanding of that point).

Comment: If `/bin/bash` has no content available on stdin, it has no commands to run and no way to prompt the user, so it exits. This is 100% normal and expected behavior.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Confused about Docker -t option to Allocate a pseudo-TTY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30137135/confused-about-docker-t-option-to-allocate-a-pseudo-tty)

Answer (score 218):

`-it` is short for `--interactive` + `--tty`. When you `docker run` with this command it takes you straight inside the container.

`-d` is short for `--detach`, which means you just run the container and then *detach* from it.  Essentially, you run container in the background.

*Edit:* So if you run the Docker container with `-itd`, it runs both the `-it` options and detaches you from the container.  As a result, your container will still be running in the background even without any default app to run.

Comment: that mean there is an error in your container.. so your container is failed to start...or maybe it didnt have any `CMD` command by default,,so it didnt run any app by default. .so if you run it in the background, it would exited immediately because it didnt have any job to do. .

Comment: @Alex, if the program in your container is something that exits when stdin is closed, there's your answer (as to why it won't run without `-i`). Similarly, if it runs commands that behave differently based on whether there's a TTY, you can get distinct behavior depending on the presence of `-t`.

Comment: @Alex, ...and to be clear, `/bin/bash </dev/null` exits immediately too, if you run it without Docker. Running `docker run` without `-i` is doing the same thing to the copy of `bash` that it starts. (Without `-t`, it has a stdin but not a TTY, so it doesn't detect itself as an interactive shell, so you get a slightly different set of behaviors).

Comment: gee.. turns out there is something similar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28212380/why-docker-container-exits-immediately

Comment: -t => TTY => TeleTYpewriter  [http://www.abouttty.com/](http://www.abouttty.com/)

Comment: I found adding `-it` solved the problem of my compiler in the container not outputting compiler errors in color, but I have no clue why it solves the issue, as I thought `-it` has only to do with stdin and interactive user input, nothing to do with stdout...Can anyone explain? Possibly a bug? Looks like `-it` makes gcc realize it's a proper terminal and outputs errors in color, without `-it` there's no color...

Comment: He is not asking about -d option which is what you answered

Comment: @AdmiralAdama, what fixes the color issue is the -t option. TTY is needed to understand the color tokens.

Comment: To the audience, consider the following as a complement ... https://stackoverflow.com/a/77990974/3665178

Answer (score 71):

`docker run -it ubuntu:xenial /bin/bash` starts the container in the interactive mode (hence `-it` flag) that allows you to interact with `/bin/bash` of the container. That means now you will have `bash` session *inside* the container, so you can `ls`, `mkdir`, or do any bash command inside the container.

The key here is the word "interactive". If you omit the flag, the container still executes `/bin/bash` but exits immediately. With the flag, the container executes `/bin/bash` then patiently waits for your input.

Comment: for what I need to use -t flag then? 
`docker run -i ubuntu:xenial /bin/bash`

Comment: You are right. I'll take back my words. Without `-t` tag one can still interact with the container, but with it, you'll have a nicer, more features terminal. You can run with `-i` and with `-it` to see the difference.

Comment: @dvnguyen what important feature is missing for example when `-i` is used alone ? I was also wondering about the difference between `-i` and `-it`

Answer (score 14):

I want to add some intuition for newbies like me.

`-it` are flags for command `docker run` or `docker container run` (they are aliases). Suggest you know what are flags and go forward:

- `-i` or `--interactive`: 
  When you type `docker run -i` this means that your terminal will transfer your input to container (app in container) until you press `ctrl-D` (leave container). For example, if some app works in container that waits for user input you can type something and that will be forwarded to the app.
- `-t` or `-tty` (Pseudo-TTY): 
  If you add this flag, your container's output is attached to your terminal. Seems it mostly about formatting output (for `bin/bash`, for example - try `ls` with and without `-t` flag), but sometimes is more important because some apps change their behaviour depending on being launched via terminal or not (text editors, for example, or mechanism of masking password with `*` implemented by terminal).

Combining two flags as `-it` gives you opportunity to make your container get your stdin and get nice formatted output from container like you are working with your nice native own terminal.

**Follow-ups**:

- How does docker understand *which app* will get my stdin (standard input)? 
  When you type `docker run -i <image> <app>`, last argument (`<app>`) will get your input.
- What are practical applications of *both flags alone*?

  - `-i` is useful when you want to interact with app in container but it's not important for you to get formatted output. For example, you want to send your data to container, get data from it and save it to file. In such case `-t` is not necessary.

  ```bash
  echo "my input" | docker run -i <image> > output.txt
  ```

  - `-t` is useful when you want terminal-like output but do not need your input to be transferred to container. Say you have script that launches inside container, outputs data in specific format and after that data is used by another script:

  ```bash
  docker run -t my-image | my-processing-script.sh
  ```

Answer (score 11):

Normal execution without any flags:

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-109-14 ~]$ sudo docker exec 69e937450dab ls
bin
boot
dev
docker-entrypoint.d
docker-entrypoint.sh
etc
```

If your command needs an input like cat, you can try:

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-109-14 ~]$ echo test | sudo docker exec 69e937450dab cat
```

Nothing will show, because there is no input stream going to the docker container. This can be achieved with the -i flag.

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-109-14 ~]$ echo test | sudo docker exec -i 69e937450dab cat
test
```

Now, let us suppose, you want the bash to start as process:

```
sudo docker exec 69e937450dab bash
```

You will see nothing, because the process started in the container. Adding the flag will do the deal:

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-109-14 ~]$ sudo docker exec -t 69e937450dab bash
root@69e937450dab:/#
```

But this does not really help, because we need an input stream, which takes our commands and can be received by the bash. Therefore, we need to combine the two:

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-109-14 ~]$ sudo docker exec -i -t 69e937450dab bash
root@69e937450dab:/# ls
bin  boot  dev  docker-entrypoint.d  docker-entrypoint.sh  etc  hi  home  lib  lib64  media  mnt  opt  proc  root  run  sbin  srv  sys  tmp  usr  var
root@69e937450dab:/#
```

small recap:

-t for attaching the bash process to our terminal

-i for being able to send inputs via STDIN for example with the keyboard to the bash in the container

Without -i can be used for commands, that don't need inputs. Without -t and bash can be used, when you dont want to attach the docker containers process to your shell.

Answer (score 0):

To complete the first answer. The options of the `run` command are need it according the `image` type to be run as a `container` instance.

If the `image` is a web server, such as `nginx`, then the `-d` option can be used to have the container running at background. It such as `docker run -d nginx`. It being possible due the `nginx` type itself.

The trick part is about if the `image` is a "Linux" type such as Alpine, Ubuntu etc

- if is executed the `docker run alpine` command then the container is created, run and immediately exit
- if is executed the `docker run -it alpine` command then the container is created and run through a terminal available for human interaction - consider it as a *foreground* mode
- If is executed the `docker run -d alpine` command then the container is created, run and immediately exit. Yes, it is correct, it is as the first scenario too. Practically the `d` option was ignored and the expected behavior to get the **background** behavior does **not** happen. Therefore ...
- if is executed the `docker run -itd alpine` command then the container is created and run at **background**