# What does -it means when running docker container

Tags: docker, terminal, docker-compose, containers, dockerfile

I'm new to docker.

What does the **-it** means when running the container using **docker run -it**.

Searched a lot but couldn't get proper documentation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [what is docker run -it flag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48368411/what-is-docker-run-it-flag)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **-it** instructs Docker to allocate a pseudo-TTY connected to the container’s stdin; creating an interactive bash shell in the container.

```
docker run --name test -it node:alpine
```