# What's the difference between `docker run -d` and `docker run -dit`?

Tags: docker, docker-run

If I would like to use it as a development environment for Node.js, is it alright to just `docker run -d`?

Do I really need the below?

```
--interactive , -i      Keep STDIN open even if not attached
--tty , -t              Allocate a pseudo-TTY
```

Comment: -d flag is for detaching the process from the shell that you are running. So the process will run in the background

Comment: Possible duplicate of [what is docker run -it flag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48368411/what-is-docker-run-it-flag)

Comment: @geoywas did you check my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a normal scenario, there is the only one difference

`-dit` Run the container in the background
`-it` Run the container in the foreground and will allocate a pseudo-terminal.

But what if the entry point is bash? like in the case of [ubuntu-dockerfile](https://github.com/tianon/docker-brew-ubuntu-core/blob/3c462555392cb188830b7c91e29311b5fad90cfe/bionic/Dockerfile). As they believe that the user will override the CMD as per their need or dependent Dockerfile.

```
# overwrite this with 'CMD []' in a dependent Dockerfile
CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

So in this case, when you only specify `-d` your container will be stopped as soon as it started. So what you need to allocate `pseudo-terminal` by adding `-dit`.

[image]

As you can see that the container is not running, let check-in stoped container.

[image]

so we can that container is exited a minutes ago. Let try with -dit
[image]

We can see that the container is running. Same case with alpine if you run alpine with `-d` it will also stop.

`docker run -d alpine`

This will exit as soon as it started, so `-dit` will Allocate a pseudo-TTY as mentioned in the documentation.