# docker run with --interactive and --tty flag

Tags: docker, containers, interactive, flags

Edit:

Someone mark duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48368411/what-is-docker-run-it-flag), but it does not explain the underlying mechanism at all.

But on contrast, [this stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30137135/confused-about-docker-t-option-to-allocate-a-pseudo-tty) solve my confusion in Case I, **but not Case II**.

---

I am newbie in docker and i am confused about the usage of --interactive, --attach flag and those concepts involved

I will show my confusion using [busybox](https://hub.docker.com/_/busybox) in docker hub.

---

**Case I** :

When I run a container using the below commands. `docker run --interactive --tty busybox sh`

A container is running and accepting input
[image]

According to the [document](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/), --interactive flag used to

> Keep STDIN open even if not attached

I don't understand what is the meaning of **even if not attached to**, attached to what?

---

**Case II** : 
Then I exit the container and try to start it using
`docker start --attach abdd796820b1` .

The terminal seems accepting input as well, but when I type ls or echo, it does not give response.
  [image]
What did the --attach flag do?

### Please help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [what is docker run -it flag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48368411/what-is-docker-run-it-flag)

Comment: @jannis, it does not, but it leads to another page [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30137135/confused-about-docker-t-option-to-allocate-a-pseudo-tty) which gives answer to most of my question. But it does not answer my last question, what id the --attach flag do.

Comment: "Then I exit the container" - how do you do that?

Comment: @jannis type exit

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are two ways in which you can interact with a running container

- attach
- exec

**--interactive flag**

As you mentioned it already says

> Keep STDIN open even if not attached

Which from my understanding means it will read inputs from your terminal/console and reacts or present output to it. If you run `docker run --tty alpine /bin/sh` and `docker run --tty --interactive alpine /bin/sh`. One with `--interactive` will react to it.

**attach**

> Attach to a running process

If the docker container was started using `/bin/bash` command, you can access it using attach, if not then you need to execute the command to create a bash instance inside the container using `exec`.

*More in depth*: If docker container is started using `/bin/bash` then it becomes containers PID 1 and `attach` command will attach you to PID 1.

**exec**

> Creates new process

If you want to create a new process inside container than exec it used like `exec` is used to execute `apt-get` command inside container without attaching to it or run a node or python script.

Eg: `docker exec -it django-prod python migrate`

See here `-i` is for interactive and `-t` is for `--tty` that is pseudo-TTY. Interactive so that you can enter if something is prompted by this command.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to provide the -i/--interactive option to forward your terminal STDIN to the container's sh.

Try this:

```
docker start -ai CONTAINER
```

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/start/