# How does docker stdin and tty flags work under the covers in containers?

Tags: docker, containers, stdin, tty

I often use these command line options, `-i` and `-t` when working with containers that I want to interact with.

```
  -i, --stdin=false: Pass stdin to the container
  -t, --tty=false: Stdin is a TTY
```

How do these work for making the containers interactive?

Comment: I usually interact with containers by making network calls to them, so I don’t need these options.  What sort of answer are you looking for; a pointer into the Docker source code?

Comment: A pointer to a good tutorial, a high-level accurate explanation. Pointer to docker source code should be okay too if it supplements the high-level explanation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [what is docker run -it flag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48368411/what-is-docker-run-it-flag)

Answer (score 5):

When you use `-i` option, the client (i.e., `docker` command) is attaching itself to the stdin of the command inside the container. If you use `-t` option, you are also [attaching a terminal](https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/ad1b781e44fa1e44b9e654e5078929aec56aed66/daemon/exec.go#L236) to the command. Some programs behave differently when connected to a terminal.

---

```
bash-3.2$ docker run -i ubuntu cat
Hey    <-- input from my stdin
Hey    --> output from cat
Hello  <-- input from my stdin
Hello  --> output from cat
```

`cat` command's stdin is connected to `docker run` command's stdin.

---

```
bash-3.2$ echo Hey | docker run -i ubuntu cat
Hey    --> output from cat
```

Here, the stdin of `cat` command is connected to stdin of `docker run` which is connected to stdout of `echo`. `docker run` exits as soon as the stdin is disconnected.

---

```
bash-3.2$ docker run -it ubuntu cat
Hey    <-- input from my stdin
Hey    --> output from cat
```

The stdin of `cat` is connected to a tty input. This tty is connected to stdin of `docker run`. stdin of `docker run` must also be a tty.

Not sure if cat behaves any differently if it's stdin is tty, but many other programs do. Example: [Some commands might hide the input when taking password input from a tty.](https://docs.python.org/2/library/getpass.html)

---

```
bash-3.2$ echo Hey | docker run -it ubuntu cat
the input device is not a TTY
```

`docker run` command's stdin is not a tty. So it cannot be connected to tty connected to `cat` command's stdin.

---

```
bash-3.2$ docker run -t ubuntu cat
Hey    <-- input from my stdin. no output from cat
```

`cat` command's stdin is connected to tty and that's it. `docker run` command's stdin is NOT connected to the `cat` because `-i` option is not used. So even you type anything into your stdin, it won't reach `cat`.

---

```
bash-3.2$ echo Hey | docker run -t ubuntu cat
```

`cat` command's stdin is connected to tty and that's it. Output of `echo` won't reach `cat`.

---

> How do these work for making the containers interactive?

Client makes an [API call](https://github.com/docker/engine/blob/master/client/container_attach.go#L56) at `/containers/{id}/attach` to the docker daemon. This HTTP connection is then [hijacked](https://github.com/docker/engine/blob/master/client/hijack.go#L20) to transport the `stdin`, `stdout`, and `stderr`(depending on options) over the underlying socket. Client and server use this socket for bidirectional streaming.

Depending on whether tty is enabled, the stream format might vary. From [container_attach.go](https://github.com/docker/engine/blob/master/client/container_attach.go#L10):

```
// If the container is using a TTY, there is only a single stream (stdout), and
// data is copied directly from the container output stream, no extra
// multiplexing or headers.
//
// If the container is *not* using a TTY, streams for stdout and stderr are
// multiplexed.
// The format of the multiplexed stream is as follows:
//
//    [8]byte{STREAM_TYPE, 0, 0, 0, SIZE1, SIZE2, SIZE3, SIZE4}[]byte{OUTPUT}
//
// STREAM_TYPE can be 1 for stdout and 2 for stderr
//
// SIZE1, SIZE2, SIZE3, and SIZE4 are four bytes of uint32 encoded as big endian.
// This is the size of OUTPUT.
```

On the client side, the data from stream is [copied onto it's stdout](https://github.com/docker/cli/blob/ae1618713f83e7da07317d579d0675f578de22fa/cli/command/container/hijack.go#L111) and [it's stdin is copied onto the stream](https://github.com/docker/cli/blob/ae1618713f83e7da07317d579d0675f578de22fa/cli/command/container/hijack.go#L144).