# Docker container exits after it starts

Tags: python, docker

I am building and running this docker container. It is running a simple `flask` server. But when I run, it exited right after.

This is my `Dockerfile`

```
FROM python:3

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

EXPOSE 8080

# CMD ["python3", "-m",  "http.server", "8080"]
CMD ["python3", "./py_server.py"]
```

and this is `py_server.py`

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

PORT = 8080

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return "Hello World"

if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run(PORT)
```

this is how I build and run the container respectively.

**build:**

```
docker build -t banuka/python-venv .
```

**run:**

```
docker run -dit -p 8080:8080 --name server1 banuka/python-venv:latest
```

Can someone tell me what I do wrong?

Comment: Can you add the logs above of the container via `docker logs server1`?

Comment: it says 'AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'startswith'`

Comment: Doesn't look like the container problem - are you able to see more logs or just this line?

Comment: Or maybe run the flask app with `debug=True`.

Comment: I fixed this, and now the problem is I can't access it. now the container is running. But now it doesn't print the hello world. When I see the logs it says `Running on http://127.0.0.1:8080/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a bug in your Flask Code. You're trying to configure Flask Server PORT in a wrong way. This will throw the error you're experiencing:

> AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'startswith'

You should configure your Flask Server Port with the following way

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return "Hello World"

if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run(host='0.0.0.0',port=8080)
```

The documentation: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.Flask.run

**EDIT**: Added host='0.0.0.0' so you can access your Flask Server remotely.

Comment: I fixed this, and now the problem is I can't access it. now the container is running. But now it doesn't print the hello world. When I see the logs it says `Running on http://127.0.0.1:8080/`

Comment: Are you running your docker locally in your machine? If so , just access from your browser http://127.0.0.1:8080. If you're hosting it remotely, you'll not be able to access it because you're binding it to localhost

Comment: Remotely. But I have a public IP assigned to the host I am running the container and have allowed all the network traffic in the security group

Comment: Look at my updated code to bind Flask to public IP. You need to add host='0.0.0.0' to app.run(), otherwise it will only bind to localhost.

Comment: app.run(host='0.0.0.0',port=8080)

Comment: Thank you. now this is working. One little question. How many times do I have to expose this port? I have exposed this in `Dockerfile` and even in the docker run command. Where only necessary?

Comment: You need to have Flask process, which is running inside a container, listening to a specific port (this is defined in the app.run() call). The Dockerfile EXPOSE is a good practice even if you're exposing the ports with -p because it acts as documentation of what ports your container expose. Then you need to tell docker run to map an internal container port to an external host port (-p 8080:8080). If you're confused with so much port definition, take a look at this [article](https://nickjanetakis.com/blog/docker-tip-59-difference-between-exposing-and-publishing-ports)

Answer (score 2):

There are several issues:

1. You want [the `-it` parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48368594/10589816), not `-dit`:

```
docker run -it -p 8080:8080 --name server1 banuka/python-venv:latest
```

2. You are passing PORT as a variable to [the `app.run()` function](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.Flask.run), so that it is interpreted as the first `host` parameter, rather than what you want, which is for it to be the `port` parameter. What you want is this: `app.run(port=8080)`
3. As @Alexandre pointed out, if you're accessing the host remotely, then you need to explicitly bind it to `host='0.0.0.0'`, so we need `app.run(host='0.0.0.0',port=8080)`

Answer (score 0):

you are maybe running procces that finishes  and then exit ?
if you run you py script and it finishes so your container will be closed to ...
try  using `while(true)  //and then your code`