# Running ubuntu docker image in background

Tags: docker, docker-container, docker-image

I was trying to run ubuntu docker image in background. So I tried below command

```sh
sudo docker container run -d --name my-ubuntu-container ubuntu:latest
```

But this command do not run the container in background. In fact the status becomes "EXITED"  on checking using

```sh
docker container ls -a
```

**But if I add "-it" flag in above command. Then the container runs in background.**

```sh
sudo docker container run -itd --name my-ubuntu-container ubuntu:latest
```

Now on checking in `docker container ls -a`. We see the status now in "UP" and it runs in background.

**Anyone can please advise why adding "-it" flag in above command along with "-d" runs the ubuntu docker image in background ?**

Comment: The standard `ubuntu` image on its own doesn't really do anything.  Is there a reason you want it running?  Do you have a more complete Dockerfile for a custom image that you're trying to run?

Answer (score 2):

You didn't specify a command so the container runs with the default command `bash`.
If you run bash interactively (`-ti`) it stays open, but otherwise it quits immediately.
If you want to run a container detached in the backgroud you can change the command from bash to a command that blocks - for example `tail -f /dev/null`.

You can run the following command and the container won't exit immediately.

```
sudo docker container run -d --name my-ubuntu-container ubuntu:latest tail -f /dev/null
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should avoid runing docker command with "sudo". Instead, add your current user to the docker group in your linux OS.

Also, you could do `docker container logs <container_id>` to see if there were eventual errors.

As stated in that other post answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/48368594/2409641

> -it is short for --interactive + --tty when you docker run with this command.. it would take you straight inside of the container,, where -d is short for --detach which means you just run the container and then detach from it so basically you run container in the background..
> edit : so if you run docker container with-itd it would run the-it options and detach you from the container, so your container still running in the background even without any default app to run..

Comment: Since you can very easily use `docker run` to compromise the host (bind-mount the host's `/etc` directory and edit `/host/etc/shadow` as root inside the container, say) it's appropriate to require `sudo` access for it.