# What is -it in this command?

Tags: linux, kubernetes, command-line-arguments

I see this command to temporarily run a pod

```
k run -it pod1 --image=cosmintitei/bash-curl --restart=Never --rm
```

What does `-it` mean here ?

I don't know about the `-it` being used here. Why is it being used? What else can it be used for?

Comment: Given how closely Kubernetes hews to Docker, the related [what is docker run -it flag?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48368411/364696) is a useful cross-link here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-it` a a short form of `-i -t` which in turn is a short form of `--stdin --tty`.

As such, this instructs kubernetes to

- pass its STDIN to the started process
- and to present STDIN as a TTY (i.e. a interactive terminal)

Comment: Thanks @Holger. How would STDIN work without a TTY ?

Comment: You can also pipe the output of a local command to a program running in the docker image, e.g. `echo "hello world" | k run -i pod1 ...`. In that case, you don't need a TTY. Some programs detect whether its STDIN is a tty and change their behavior based on that (to e.g. enable/disable support for interactive menus, use different defaults, ...) Check the respective program's documentation for details.