# Why does this docker image accept my command input?

Tags: node.js, docker, dockerfile

Following a instruction from [nextjs's repo README](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-docker), I can successfully run the docker image with `docker run -p 3000:3000 nextjs-docker`. And I also make other `Dockerfile` which executes `yarn start`, this also can run.

I'm curious while I can stop the container made of `Dockerfile 1` with `Ctrl + C`, `Dockerfile 2` can not be stopped. But if I run the letter one with `docker run -it -p 3000:3000 nextjs-docker`, it can stop.

Why the docker container made of `Dockerfile 2` needs to attach `-it`?

Dockerfile 1

```
FROM node:18-alpine AS base

# Install dependencies only when needed
FROM base AS deps
# Check https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/tree/b4117f9333da4138b03a546ec926ef50a31506c3#nodealpine to understand why libc6-compat might be needed.
RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat
WORKDIR /app

# Install dependencies based on the preferred package manager
COPY package.json yarn.lock* package-lock.json* pnpm-lock.yaml* ./
RUN \
  if [ -f yarn.lock ]; then yarn --frozen-lockfile; \
  elif [ -f package-lock.json ]; then npm ci; \
  elif [ -f pnpm-lock.yaml ]; then yarn global add pnpm && pnpm i --frozen-lockfile; \
  else echo "Lockfile not found." && exit 1; \
  fi


# Rebuild the source code only when needed
FROM base AS builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=deps /app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY . .

# Next.js collects completely anonymous telemetry data about general usage.
# Learn more here: https://nextjs.org/telemetry
# Uncomment the following line in case you want to disable telemetry during the build.
# ENV NEXT_TELEMETRY_DISABLED 1

RUN yarn build

# If using npm comment out above and use below instead
# RUN npm run build

# Production image, copy all the files and run next
FROM base AS runner
WORKDIR /app

ENV NODE_ENV production
# Uncomment the following line in case you want to disable telemetry during runtime.
# ENV NEXT_TELEMETRY_DISABLED 1

RUN addgroup --system --gid 1001 nodejs
RUN adduser --system --uid 1001 nextjs

COPY --from=builder /app/public ./public

# Set the correct permission for prerender cache
RUN mkdir .next
RUN chown nextjs:nodejs .next

# Automatically leverage output traces to reduce image size
# https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/output-file-tracing
COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next/standalone ./
COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next/static ./.next/static

USER nextjs

EXPOSE 3000

ENV PORT 3000
# set hostname to localhost
ENV HOSTNAME "0.0.0.0"

CMD ["node", "server.js"]
```

Dockerfile 2

```
FROM node:18-alpine AS base

# Copy files for starting app
COPY .next ./.next
COPY node_modules ./node_modules
COPY package.json ./

EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["yarn","start"]
```

Answer (score 1):

That is intended behavior because you did not start the container in `detached mode` using `docker run -d`.

The options you mentioned (`-it`) have a different purpose, see here: [what is docker run -it flag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48368411/what-is-docker-run-it-flag)

[Link to the Docker documentation.](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/)

Comment: Thank you. My understanding was incorrect. I modified the question.