# What would happen if I ran `docker run -i` rather than `docker run -it`

Tags: docker, tty

The `docker run` documentation says that `-t`  is `Allocate a pseudo-TTY`.

My problem with running docker with `-it`, is that with `-t` on, I cannot redirect `STDOUT` and `STDERR` into files.

It is important for me to run docker on interactive mode, as I need the user to be able to interrupt the running process (or just write to `STDIN`).

- Is there anything I should be concerned about when running a docker container interactively, but without `-t`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Confused about Docker -t option to Allocate a pseudo-TTY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30137135/confused-about-docker-t-option-to-allocate-a-pseudo-tty)

Comment: Also: [Error “The input device is not a TTY”](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43099210/596285)

Comment: Thank you guys. Your links helped me a lot.