# Docker: Executing Python script

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker

I have a python script that i am trying to get running correctly in a docker container. I am struggling with the CMD section of the DOCKERFILE.

I can get the script to run correctly from my terminal that shows the live updates continuously as per the code in the script by opening an interactive python console and then running the following commands

```
exec(open(“coin_flip_demo_v1.0.py").read())
test = coin_flip_demo()
test._run_()
```

My DOCKERFILE looks like

```
FROM python:3.6

RUN mkdir src
ADD . /src/
RUN pip install pandas
WORKDIR /src/
EXPOSE 32768 32769 32770
CMD [ "python", "./coin_flip_demo_v1.0.py" ]
```

When i try to run the container it doesn't give any errors however when i run `docker ps` there are no containers showing

Just for reference

`coin_flip_demo_v1.0.py` is the script i am trying to run

`coin_flip_demo` is my main class in that script

`_run_` is a module within the main class.

Let me know if you need any more info to solve this issue.

Thanks

Comment: Did you try to run the container with -it option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To run interactive processes in a container, you should start the container with -i -t option.

This allocates a tty for the container.

```
docker run -it <img>[:tag]
```

Also refer to the answers in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30137135/confused-about-docker-t-option-to-allocate-a-pseudo-tty) SO question.

Apart from the `-it` option.. you should also make your python script to directly run (as you have mentioned in the `Dockerfile` so)

Can you run the script directly from the terminal? like this

```
python ./coin_flip_demo_v1.0.py
```

If not add the following lines to the end of the python file

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    test = coin_flip_demo()
    test._run_()
```

Comment: Hi, yes i ran it with those commands and it gives the same result no errors, but no containers showing when running docker ps. If i run the command docker ps -a then it shows the container as being started but obviously not continuing to run.

Comment: I am wondering if i need to create a bash file with the commands i listed above to run instead of just trying to run the single 'CMD [ "python", "./coin_flip_demo_v1.0.py" ]' in the dockerfile, however i am not sure if this is the proper way of doing it.

Comment: @AlHennessey Yes, your python script should be executable.. I have edited my answer to address this. You can use a bash script as you say, or preferable is to make the python script itself executable properly.