# Send command to running container using attach without docker exec

Tags: docker

I have a looped process running in a docker container that accepts typed commands. At the moment I have to use `docker attach <container>` and then type my command such as `restart` before exiting out.

I can't use `docker exec` as far as I know as the process is already running that I want to interact with so is there anyway I can programmatically pass in a command to `docker attach`?

Edit: This is a command inside of the program running, not one that's available with the shell

Comment: you can use `docker exec` when the service is already running, `docker exec container_name command`

Comment: I can't because the command is not available with the shell, it's a running process already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [described here](https://serverfault.com/a/947763/93281), you can use `socat` for this: `echo 'restart' | socat EXEC:'docker attach <container>',pty STDIN`

Another full example:

```sh
# Run the program in docker, here bash, in background
docker run -it --rm --name test ubuntu &
# Send "ls -la" to the bash running inside docker
echo 'ls -la' | socat EXEC:'docker attach test',pty STDIN
# Show the result
docker logs test
```

Answer (score 2):

A solution might be to use something like:

```
echo "your input here" | docker attach <your container>
```

but... this requires to not use the `-t` option which might cause you other problems...

---

Check this issue: [Redirect stdin to `docker attach`](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/1858) where Michael Crosby provides an example:

> This issue has been resolved.
>
> ```
> docker run -i busybox sh -c "while true; do cat /dev/stdin; sleep 1; done;"
> test
>
> # ... from another terminal
> echo test | docker attach 27f04f3fd73a
> ```

What should be noticed here is that **it doesn't work** when you run the container with `--tty , -t   (Allocate a pseudo-TTY)` option. I haven't understood completely why this happens so I won't try to explain it, some things have been already written here: [Confused about Docker -t option to Allocate a pseudo-TTY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30137135/confused-about-docker-t-option-to-allocate-a-pseudo-tty)

---

Also, from the `docker run` [reference](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#foreground):

> For interactive processes (like a shell), you must use `-i` `-t` together in order to allocate a tty for the container process. `-i` `-t` is often written `-it` as you’ll see in later examples.**Specifying `-t` is forbidden when the client is receiving its standard input from a pipe**, as in:
>
> ```
> $ echo test | docker run -i busybox cat
> ```

Comment: I've ran into the issue with the ``-t`` flag probably being used in docker-compose, I get the error ``the input device is not a TTY`` when I try and pipe to it.

Answer (score 0):

It's also possible to send a command to a docker container which has a terminal, using `expect`:

send-t.exp:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
set container [lindex $argv 0]
set command [lindex $argv 1]
spawn docker attach $container
send -- "$command\n"
expect "*\n"
expect "*\n"
# set timeout 1
# expect eof
```

Usage:

`send-t.exp container 'command args'`

Example:

`send-t.exp my-container 'find /'`