# how to enter docker container after pulling image via the `-it` command on mac osx?

Tags: docker, terminal, aws-lambda

I am following this [guide](https://medium.com/i-like-big-data-and-i-cannot-lie/how-to-create-an-aws-lambda-python-3-6-deployment-package-using-docker-d0e847207dd6) to make a aws lambda package for a piece of python code. The only difference is that I am pulling a python3.7 image like so:

```
docker run  lambci/lambda:build-python3.7 aws --version
```

According to the documentation I should be able to run `uname` and to check that I am inside the linux environment. I am not inside this environment.

I am unable to enter the docker image after it has completed the pull, how do I enter the docker container after it has completed being pulled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify a command (looks like that image does not have default one). Also add `-it` as parameters, then it works:

`docker run -it lambci/lambda:build-python3.7 bash`

https://serverfault.com/questions/757210/no-command-specified-from-re-imported-docker-image-container

```
$: man docker
-i, --interactive                    Keep STDIN open even if not attached
-t, --tty                            Allocate a pseudo-TTY
```

I did not get why `-i` is needed as it is not run in `detached` mode, but does not work w/out it. Welcome explanations from experts in comments.

Comment: This answer helps explain why it is needed, https://stackoverflow.com/a/40026942/1794802