# Pipe stdin to docker exec on Windows

Tags: docker, exec, stdin, tty

I'm trying to import SQL data to a docker container. Using git bash / mintty:

```
> docker exec -it 79c5c16acca0 mysql -uusername -ppassword dbname
the input device is not a TTY.  If you are using mintty, try prefixing the command with 'winpty'

> winpty docker exec -it 79c5c16acca0 mysql -uusername -ppassword dbname
stdin is not a tty
```

I have also tried Powershell:

```
> Get-Content powo.sql | docker exec -it 79c5c16acca0 mysql -uusername -ppassword dbname
the input device is not a TTY.  If you are using mintty, try prefixing the command with 'winpty'
```

FWIW, running `bash` in the container works fine:

```
> docker exec -it 79c5c16acca0 bash
root@79c5c16acca0:/#
```

Answer (score 4):

This will work if you remove `-t`.

```
$ docker run --rm --name example alpine sleep 100

$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE     COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS          PORTS                 NAMES
49968909e3e4   alpine    "sleep 100"              8 seconds ago    Up 7 seconds                          example

$ echo "hi" | docker exec -it example cat
the input device is not a TTY.  If you are using mintty, try prefixing the command with 'winpty'

$ echo "hi" | docker exec -i example cat
hi
```

This is true for `bash`, `ps`, and Git bash.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54254380/4303355) is the best reference I can find on what `-i` and `-t` do (in language that I can understand).

From that, my guess is that you can't use `-t` when piping in content as `-t` implies the input is from a terminal device, but in this case the input is the pipe (which itself is from the terminal device).

Comment: For those using Docker Compose, you also need to pass `-T` (`--no-tty`) because `docker compose exec` allocates a TTY by default.