# Can't pass input from SQL dump file via arrow to mysql command within docker

Tags: mysql, linux, docker, mariadb

I have MariaDB (`foobar_db`) running in local environment in Docker. I have a SQL file `some_sql_dump.sql` that I want to run on this database. This is what I tried:

```
docker exec -t container_id_here mysql -u root -prootpass foobar_db < some_sql_dump.sql
```

This takes me into MariaDB's monitor:

```
Reading table information for completion of table and column names
You can turn off this feature to get a quicker startup with -A                     
                                                                                   
Welcome to the MariaDB monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.                        
Your MariaDB connection id is 11                                                   
Server version: 10.4.13-MariaDB-1:10.4.13+maria~bionic mariadb.org binary distribution

Copyright (c) 2000, 2018, Oracle, MariaDB Corporation Ab and others.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

MariaDB [foobar_db]>
```

It seems like using the arrow (`<`) to pass in input from `some_sql_dump.sql` did not work correctly. Why did the arrow not work, and how can I make it run the SQL from the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just used the "--interactive , -i" option and it seems to work.

```bash
$ docker exec -i {container_id} mysql -u root -prootpass foobar_db < some_sql_dump.sql
```

Comment: Thanks - do you have any insight as to why this works but what I did doesn't work?

Comment: Your welcome, cheryllium! The accepted answer in this question looks to address the options usage correctly: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30137135/confused-about-docker-t-option-to-allocate-a-pseudo-tty

Comment: If you don't run with `-i`, no stdin is attached. If you run with `-it`, you'll get the error message `the input device is not a TTY`.