# Differences between docker -i -t and -it flags

Tags: docker, flags

I'm a little confused by some docker flags, and more particularly by the "i", "t" and "it" flags.

First, is "docker run -it" equivalent to "docker run -i -t" ?

Second, what does "Allocate a pseudo-TTY" exactly means (it is the documentation of the "-t" flag) ?

I've conducted a couple of tests with an image (called hello-world) having

```
CMD ["echo", "Hello docker world !!!"]
```

or

```
ENTRYPOINT  ["echo", "Hello docker world !!!"]
```

The following commands :

- `docker run -i -t hello-world`
- `docker run -i hello-world`
- `docker run -t hello-world`
- `docker run -it hello-world`
- `docker run hello-world`

all resulted in the display of the text "Hello world". I would expect at least the last one to not display anything...

Comment: I think `i` means interactive and `t` means tag. You can use multiple one letter parameters with a single dash in together therefore `-it` should be equivalent with `-i -t`.

Comment: As you mentioned, `-t` or `--tty` allocates a pseudo-TTY. It simply means that a terminal is allocated which you can use to interact with container. If you want to know why they used the term _pseudo-TTY_, then you should read about the history of Unix, `tty`, physical terminals which were used to access computers back then etc. If you try something like `docker run -t ubuntu bash`, you'll see that you'll get a terminal but you can't interact with the container. That's where the `-i` or `--interactive` comes to the stage. This flag _Keep STDIN open even if not attached_.

Comment: So, if you now try `docker run -i -t ubuntu bash`, you'll be able to use the terminal and execute commands in a container. And with most CLI tools, you can combine those short option into one. You can say `docker run -it` instead of `docker run -i -t`. Just like you can use `ls -lah` instead of `ls -l -a -h`.

Comment: Ok, starts to be more clear. So docker run has its stdout directed to the terminal from where it is executed (in contrast to docker start). Without -i there is simply no way to interact with the container. Adding -i let me interact but in a very basic form (for instance I have to type "exit", I cannot ctrl-c. And adding -t provides a full blown terminal.

Answer (score 4):

Those are called flags and a flag can either be combined or separated, either in short (-) or long format (--). So:

```
docker run --interactive --tty hello-world

docker run --interactive -t hello-world

docker run -i --tty hello-world

docker run -i -t hello-world

docker run -it hello-world
```

are all the same.

As to how -i and -t works, refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30137135/confused-about-docker-t-option-to-allocate-a-pseudo-tty)

Comment: You can't combine long format, though

Answer (score 0):

In this above simple example it will work the same.

In the last example container will print "Hello..." and exit in contrary to when you start interactive mode: https://phoenixnap.com/kb/docker-run-command-with-examples (-i -t -it will work the same)

For the difference cmd and entrypoint refer here: [What is the difference between CMD and ENTRYPOINT in a Dockerfile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21553353/what-is-the-difference-between-cmd-and-entrypoint-in-a-dockerfile)