# Cannot pipe to docker run with stdin attached

Tags: bash, docker, containers, pipe

I am newbie on Docker. Seems the following *pipe* prints nothing. If I am right, the `-a stdin` attaches my host *stdin* to the container process's *stdin*.

```sh
~ $ echo test | docker run -a stdin -a stdout -a stderr --rm alpine cat -
```

When I add the `-i` option, it does print the "test":

```sh
~ $ echo test | docker run -i -a stdin -a stdout -a stderr --rm alpine cat -
test
```

Why must we append the `-i` option?

I did read this post [Confused about Docker -t option to Allocate a pseudo-TTY](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30137135), but still confused by options like `-a, -d, -t, -i`. For example, is there any difference between the following two runs?

```sh
~ $ docker run -a stdin -a stdout -it ubuntu /bin/bash

~ $ docker run -it ubuntu /bin/bash
```

---

After some search, I *think* the `-i` option's purpose is to make the *stdin* of PID 1 **open** which by default is **closed**.

Comment: I think those streams are attached by default. Eg. you can simplify this example to `echo foo |  docker run -i --rm alpine cat -`

Comment: @NickODell, yep. But why `-i` prints the text while `-a stdin` not.

Comment: well technically, the help says this for -i  `Keep STDIN open even if not attached`. So I would think that if its attached its kept open without -i but when its not attached you can keep it open with -i. In that sense using -a STDIN should work the same as -i. Maybe you need to uppercase it.

Comment: Well I just tried  `docker run -i busybox cat < text.txt` works but `docker run -a STDIN -a STDOUT -a STDERR busybox cat < text.txt` doesnt.

Comment: @TheFool yep, `-a STDIN` does *not* pipe/redirect data to the container process. That's the part I don't understand.